# How can I trigger click after a short delay in my HTML button?

Tags: jquery, html, click, delay

There is a technique called duell and it is used for accessibility reasons in websites. It is used from people that can only move a device (i.e mouse.) and it works like this. On hover effect hovering lasts longer than lets se as an example 1 sec then the click function is triggered. I want to emulate this with jQuery for my button elements in my HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(function() {
    var clearTimeout = function(b) {
      window.clearTimeout($(b).data("hoverTimer"));
    }
    $("button").hover(function() {
      var button = $(this);
      button.data("hoverTimer", window.setTimeout(function() {
        button.trigger("click");
      }, 1000));
    }, function() {
      clearTimeout(this)
    }).click(function() {
      clearTimeout(this)
    });
})();
```

Edited to avoid multiple clicks. (Thanks,  Alnitak)

Answer (score 9):

```
var timer = null;
$('button').hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);

function mouseIn() {
   timer = setTimeout(triggerClick, 3000);
}

function mouseOut() {
   clearTimeout(timer );
}

function triggerClick() {
  $('button').trigger('click');
}
```

This solution uses timers. Starts a timer when you hover over the element and clears it when you stop hovering over it. Obviously this only works for 1 button, but you could easily modify it to work for all buttons on your page.

Answer (score 5):

I knocked out a quick jQuery plugin to do what you asked.

Source (and demo) at http://jsfiddle.net/raybellis/tF833/

For reference here, the (current) code looks like:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.duell = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var timer = null;
            var el = this;
            var stopTimer = function() {
                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = null;
                }
            };

            var startTimer = function() {
                stopTimer();
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    $(el).click();
                }, 1000);
            };

            // make sure other clicks turn off the timer too
            $(el).click(stopTimer);

            // handle mouseenter, mouseleave
            $(el).hover(startTimer, stopTimer);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: not bad for my first plugin, although it is a _little_ rough around the edges :)  For bonus points, the timeout should be configurable and there'd be visual feedback when the simulated click happens.